# Windows Form Label position issue

Tags: winforms, user-controls, position, label, size

I have a `UserControl` which has a `Label` at the bottom right corner defined as followed:

```
        this.lblInspectionName.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblInspectionName.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 10.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
        this.lblInspectionName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 7);
        this.lblInspectionName.Name = "lblInspectionName";
        this.lblInspectionName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(113, 19);
        this.lblInspectionName.TabIndex = 0;
        this.lblInspectionName.Text = "___";
```

Its `Text` content changes based on other events. The problem is that when the `Label` gets bigger, it goes to left (as I want otherwise it exceeds the right border), but when it gets smaller again the location is the same as the previous case and it's positioned too left.

[image: Initial situation] [image: Second] [image: Third]

Do you know how I can let the label grows to left when necessary keeping always a certain distance/margin to the right border? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Doing as suggested, the situation is the following:

[image: Dock and text alignment properties updadted - Autosize = false]

Comment: Not able to test on a user control now, but did you try with Dock = Bottom and TextHAlign = Right?

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. The label goes to the bottom left border covering the other controls.

Answer (score 1):

I would add these properties settings

```
this.lblInspectionName.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
this.lblInspectionName.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomRight;
```

But you need to set the AutoSize back to false.

```
// Comment out this line. False is default
// this.lblInspectionName.AutoSize = true;
```

Comment: Doing as you suggested, the label goes to bottom left border of the UserControl, covering the other controls.

Comment: I found that if you remove the AutoSize setting then it works as expected

Comment: Also you should remove the Location setting and let the winform engine full use the docking and alignment properties

Comment: Yes, it solves the label position problem. It covers the other controls but probably I have to fix the other Dock properties.

Comment: I'm worried that DockStyle.Bottom is responsible of the other controls overlapping. I'm going to download the image.

Comment: Uhm, yes they overlap because the other controls are probably in a fixed position. Difficult to say but probably you need to set also for these control the Dock to Bottom but then you need to work with the Z Order to have them in the right position (Format->Order->BringToFront/SendToBack) Also putting the interested controls inside a panel and then docking the panel could be another possibility